# SSSD Ubuntu 16.04 Joining WIndows 2012 Domain

Tags: 16.04, windows, samba, domain-server, join

I am new to Linux. I am trying to join a Ubuntu 16.04 server to a Windows domain. I came across [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html). I used a similar article for 14.04 which worked with very little issues.

When I run `sudo apt install krb5-user samba sssd ntp` I get error messages :

```
adduser: Warning: The home directory `/var/lib/sss' does not belong to the user                                                           you are currently creating.
Warning: found usr.sbin.sssd in /etc/apparmor.d/force-complain, forcing complain                                                           mode
Warning failed to create cache: usr.sbin.sssd
Job for sssd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.                                                           See "systemctl status sssd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
sssd.service couldn't start.
```

I am not sure why this is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

i built a script for it. here you go! https://github.com/PierreGoude/Linux-Active-Directory-join-script

Comment: It will work.. for ubuntu 16 you dont need krb5-user. I have joined many computers with this script and made improvments today